# CONCAT substring

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which carries around 172 entries, with different column names, however I want to update all of them with a simple query.
I have a name entered in the `name` column (http://prntscr.com/j9qeg6)

I would like to replace the III with I've using a simple query,
Now I've been checking and trying however it does not seem to work.
I used the following query which got me closest to the result however its not working.

```
UPDATE item_template SET name = CONCAT("IV", SUBSTRING(name, LENGTH("III ")+1));
```

Does anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apostrophe `'` instead of Double quotes `"`

You can try use `REPLACE` function.

```
UPDATE item_template 
SET name = REPLACE(name, ' III', ' IV');
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4b8d6/1*

Comment: Probably sufficient for this particular problem, but you want to replace `' III'` with `' IV'`, just in case `III` could appear in other contexts.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right `' III'` will better than `'III'`,thank for your remind